# django 1.7 relation "auth_user" does not exist in migrate but fine in tests

Tags: python, django, migration

I'm updating a django-1.5 project to django-1.7.2 and when migrating I keep getting "relation "auth_user" does not exist". However if I run python manage.py test -v2 to see the process of database creation/migration

```
Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
Applying subscription.0001_initial... OK
```

Migrations turn out fine. Am I missing a step? It is my belief that one does not need to syncdb anymore simply

```
python manage.py migrate
```

But doing that does not apply migrations for django apps.

Note: I'm not using a custom User class just the regular django.contrib.auth.models.User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you faked auth migrations already on real database?

Try to check

```
select * from django_migrations where app='auth'
```

and if any records exists, delete them.

Comment: Yes that was it, silly me. I used the same name as a previous test database that already had these table and I thought it was completely empty. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and then

```
python manage.py migrate
```

The migrate does indeed apply the migrations, but they first need to be created. These two steps are more or less the replacement of the old syncdb.

Comment: yeah it's weird I do this but I still get this error. Then I try python manage.py makemigrations auth = "No changes detected in app 'auth'", or python manage.py migrate auth = "No migrations to apply" as if migrations have already been applied but they haven't